# trouble building react component that has ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple `node.js` app using `reactjs` tutorial on comment box example.
I am having trouble saving comments to database, which is mongodb.

Here's the code,

comment_box.jsx

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({

   loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    var commBox = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: commBox.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        commBox.setState({data: data});
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var commBox = this;
    var comments = this.state.data;
// Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
// id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
// not use Date.now() for this and would have a more robust system in place.
    comment.id = Date.now();

    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: commBox.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment    
      }).done(function(data) {
        commBox.setState({data: data});
    });
  },
```

api.js

```
//api for listing and posting comments

//bring comments model
var Comment = require('../models/comment.js');


exports.post = function(req, res, err) {
    new Comment({comment: req.comment, author: req.author}).save(function() {
      if(!err) {
        console.log('saved');
      }
      else {
        console.log('save failed');
      }

    });
}

exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Comment.find(function(err, comments) {
    res.send(comments);
  });
}
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var Router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var api = require('../controllers/api.js');

Router.get('/', api.list);

Router.post('/', api.post);

module.exports = Router;
```

server.js

```
// set up the RESTful API, handler methods are defined in api.js
app.use('/api/v1/*', require('./server/routes/router.js'));
```

The error is in exports.post in api.js the req doesn't come with body for some reason, I tried debugging with node inspector but couldn't see what the problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need me post any further details to understand the question. Basically, in console I get error ERR_RESPONSE_EMPTY.

more details on the error,
I am running node server on my apple machine os x el capitan, routing is done by using expressjs, after I load the page react mounts the components which contains a comment form where you can get to add comments and post them. So ,here when I hit post button the ajax call should post the comment to the database and react component will get updated. But , the post call is not happening. In my comment_box.jsx code you can see the post call. the bit I posted here in server.js will handle the routes. and I have a router.js file and api.js that contains methods for posting and listing comments.

I was expecting when a comment is submitted, the form submit will trigger the react function to do the ajax call and update the database. But, it's not happening I get ERR_RESPONSE_EMPTY.

Comment: Could you narrow down the concern?

Comment: Its difficult to catch the actual problem. I'd suggest you to use some parser middle-ware to get the `form-data` (if you haven't yet). [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) is quite nice and easy to use. after including it .. just use `app.use(require('body-parser'));` in your main `app.js`. and then get the body params using `req.body.comment` and `req.body.author`.

Comment: ok, I have to using body-parser. But, I am not sure how it's going to solve my problem. Here's the link to my repo on github (https://github.com/dnmahendra/Nodejs-project.git) if you wanna give a try to get more idea on what's happening.

Comment: @Mah3ndra You should probably add the OS and the language it was written in to the tags. ;) If you do not bother to narrow down your problem, why should somebody you are asking for help _for free_?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg how about now? I have edited my post. If you are into reactjs and had gone through their example on thier website, you will get what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I know about reactjs. And I know the example. _And_ I know about debugging. Have you checked that your router provides the correct data, for example by simply calling the URL with your web browser? If it gives the correct data, neither your router not MongoDB would be affected, and you could simply omit that in your question. If it does not give the correct data, you problem is not with reacts,ajax or JavaScript... I think you get the picture by now.

Comment: Yes, passing the routes in url is working. GET call is working fine and my browser shows the output from database as well. Usually, for a post request you see body like req.body should work but for req.body.comment is giving me error like 'comment of undefined'.

Comment: @Minato body-parser did the trick. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Mah3ndra LOL, I coudn't even get the server up and running :P .. 404  not found... can you tell me which tutorial are you following... ? just a bit curious.

Comment: @Minato How you are running the server? Did you try nodemon src/server.js? I am playing with webpack express and react. I am following their respective docs. The tutorial I was talking about is on react official website, the comment box one.

Comment: Oh.. I am just running the npm start task.. And it only starts the webpack.. Well it should be this way.. Until you are serving your client side from one location an your server from other

Comment: @Minato oh yeah..initially I started with only webpack and then I integrated express..I have to change the script tasks..can you help me with one last thing? The post request is getting successful, when click on post button the record is getting added but I am seeing POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/comment 404 not found error. I don't see ajax call is getting completed as I don't see it is going inside .done or .fail.

Comment: it'll be nice if you could upload the current state of the project so that I can clone it and help you accordingly

Comment: It's up to date now, you can clone it and run using npm start..let me know if you bump into any issues.